# Android Studio - Load file using Intent on Activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 2 Activity, `Activity A` and `Activity B`. I call `Activity B` from `Activity A` using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY, at `Activity B`, I have form upload file, it's just button with onclick to open file storage using Intent. My problem is after selecting the file it not going back to `Activity B` but go to `Activity A` instead. I know it's because FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY but I must use it because I using onActivityResult() on `Activity A`, is there any suggestion to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: That flag has nothing to do with onActivityResult. Please elaborate.

Comment: `I have form upload file, ` Where? How? What? You go to quick!

Comment: @blackapps at Activity B

Comment: I already write it please read carefully
Where = Activity B
How = it's just button with onclick to open file storage using Intent
What = what do you mean "what"?